# Integrate $f(x,y)=1+xy$ over the region between two disks of radius $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So $D=\{(x,\,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: 1\leq x^2+y^2\leq2 \text{ and } y\geq 0\}$, so I change to polar coordinates: $x=r\cos(\theta),\,y=r\sin(\theta)$ for $ r\in [1,\,\sqrt{2}]$ and $\theta\in[0,\pi]$. The problem is that I'm not quite sure how to make the change of variables for the function $f(x,\,y)=1+xy$. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Anywhere you see $x$ or $y$ you will replace by $r\cos(\theta)$ or $r\sin(\theta)$ respectively. From this you can get $f(r,\theta)=1+r^2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)$. Now you can use trig identities to reduce this to a difference of $\sin$s.

Comment: @Tony: There needs to be a Jacobian determinant somewhere too.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of polar coordinates, split into $\iint 1\,dxdy + \iint xy\,dxdy$. The latter integral is $0$ by symmetry; the former is just the area of $D$.

Comment: This is a lot simpler than using polar coordinates!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use polar coordinates, you could take

$\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi}\int_1^{\sqrt{2}}\left(1+r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta\right)r\,dr\,d\theta=\int_0^{\pi}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot3\cos\theta\sin\theta\right)d\theta$